# Prometheus | filter query based on another metric

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I have two metrics:

node_filesystem_files

```
node_filesystem_files{device="/dev/nvme0n1p1",endpoint=“metrics”,fstype=“xfs”,**instance**=“10.64.0.113:9100”,job=“node-exporter”,mountpoint="/",namespace=“observability”,pod=“prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-kpjhq”,service=“prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter”}
```

kube_node_role

```
kube_node_role{endpoint=“http”,**instance**=“10.64.43.50:8080”,job=“kube-state-metrics”,namespace=“observability”,node=“ip-10-64-0-113.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal”,pod=“prometheus-kube-state-metrics-69447598b7-fkshq”,**role**=“solr”,service=“prometheus-kube-state-metrics”}
```

Problem statement:

I want to filter node_filesystem_files on basis of **role** which is present in `kube_node_role`. The common link in both the metrics is instance. Can someone suggest a way or query by which both the metrics can be linked to generate output of `node_filesystem_files` based on roles.